# Visual Studio and Azure: publication profile only uploads new files, doesn't overwrite previous

Tags: azure, visual-studio, publish

I'm publishing my project with a Publication Profile downloaded from azure (this was already configured by a previous developer).

The problem is, when publishing, only new files are uploaded, but modified files are not overwritten.

I checked option "Remove additional files at destination" and modified files did **disappear**, and weren't re-uploaded, so now I have errors.

Searching through publishing options I don't find other options to force this overwritting.

Any ideas?

Comment: `Only few files are uploaded` what are the missing files ?

Comment: Are you able to run the application immediately after downloading the files from Azure ?

Comment: Only **new** files, I mean pre-existing files are not replaced.

Comment: I am not able to execute application immediately, as Azure has a compiled copy, source code is in GIT repository. When publishing, compiled code should be uploaded.

Comment: Could you please share your app folder structure

Comment: Ucheck `Remove additional files at destination` option.That is teh setting which stops the updated/modified files (which are already in the publish folder).

Comment: Modified files aren't updated with any option, whether checked or unchecked, thanks anyway

Comment: Which files (what extension) you are trying to update ?

Comment: You can try different option as well.

Comment: They are view files, *.cshtml and Scripts *.js

Comment: Working on it, will provide the answer in detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I checked option "Remove additional files at destination" and modified files did **disappear**, and weren't re-uploaded, so now I have errors.

The option `Remove additional files at destination` will allow to publish only the newly created files in the Application (which are not in the publish Profile).

Even though you have made changes in the already existing files, as the file already exists in the deployed publish folder. The modified file gets ignored/deleted.

***Check the below Workaround.***

Initially I have deployed a sample WebApp using `Import Profile` (downloaded Publish Profile from Azure App Service).

***Initial Output:***

[image]

Now, I have made few changes in the existing  `Privacy.cshtml` file and also created a new  `Sample.cshtml` file.

- As you have mentioned checked the `Remove additional files at destination` and re-published the App.

[image]

- I have tried with both the options (by checking and unchecking Remove additional files at destination).
- You can see that the WebApp is updated with the newly created `Sample.cshtml` file and the changes in the existing `Primary Page.

[image]

- Tried with both `.cshtml` and `js` files.

[image]

> source code is in GIT repository.

As your Source is already in Git Repo, update the Git Repository with the newly `modified/created` code files, Push the changes to Git Hub and deploy the App using GitHub from `Deployment Center`.

[image]

If you still face issues in publishing the Application, suggest you to publish the App using the `New Profile` => `Azure` => `Azure App Service`.
[image]

Select the same `App Service` from which you have downloaded the Publish Profile.
[image]